# Good way to load ressources

Tags: java, loading

I am developping a server application in Java. I need to load some ressources from different sources (XML and a Database). So, i need some advice on how to cleanly implement the loading.

I have a class "ServerX" who create some "Memory" object, it's those objets who'll hold the loaded ressources.

I've found two different way of loading, but both seems dirty.

## 1

```
public class ServerX
{
    /**
    Will hold the houses for further use.
    */
    private Memory<House> houses;
    
    public ServerX()
    {
        houses = new Memory<House>();
        
        loadHouses();
        loadXX();
        loadYY();
        LoadZZ();
        Load...
    }
    
    private void loadHouses()
    {
        //Pseudo code
        List<House> loaded = loadHousesFromDatabase();
        houses.addAll(loaded);
    }
    
    private void loadXX();
    
    ...
}
```

But this way, it flood my "ServerX" class.

## 2

```
public interface Loader
{
    public void loadHouses(Memory<House> toFill);
    public void loadXX(Memort<XX> toFill);
    public void loadYY(Memort<YY> toFill);
    public void loadZZ(Memort<ZZ> toFill);
}

public class SimpleLoader implements Loader
{
    //Implements methods.
}

public class ServerX
{
    /**
    Will hold the houses for further use.
    */
    private Memory<House> houses;
    
    public ServerX(Loader loader)
    {
        houses = new Memory<House>();
        loader.loadHouses(houses);
        loader.loadXX...
    }
}
```

But this way, i think i fall into the Poltergeist antipattern, because i create a new loader only to do the request to the database/XML file, and then it's garbage-collected.

So, is there another way to do it, or is one of my solutions good enough?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One pattern you can consider is the [Service Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) Pattern. An explanation of Service Locator can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/ServiceLocator.html).

Basically, a service locator is a registry + cache combined to find the resource once and keep it in memory for object retrieval during the lifecycle of the application. Service Locator is mainly implemented using the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution using a `Loader` interface and multiple implementations (`XMLLoader` and `DBLoader`) is good. However, keep the loader and the server decoupled by making the load methods return a new `Memory` instance instead of passing the memory as a reference. Add a copyAll method in Memory class to copy the contents of one memory into another memory. ( See ArrayList.addAll or System.arrayCopy in javadoc )